# Deploy project with database in WPF

Tags: wpf, sql-server

I'm trying deploy a WPF project with database (sql server), but when I did following some tutorials on the internet, when another computer installs and runs it, it causes an error related to the connection string. Please help me and sorry for my bad English. :(

Comment: my friend's lap installed it, he said this error relate to connecstring and it's in a xml file.

Comment: Can you show us the connection string? I guess there is a server name and/or account name in it, or it is using trusted security and the user is not running the application with enough privileges.